# Convergence issues in a3c

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I've built an A3C implementation in keras using this as referance: https://jaromiru.com/2017/03/26/lets-make-an-a3c-implementation/
And I'm using custom environment, where an agent has a choise of purchasing some items, selling or exchanging them given their price as state. And it is given positive rewards for good deals and negative rewards for bad deals. I have tested it on DQN in the past and it sucessfully converged showing really good results. But when I use the same environment in A3C, it results in model just choosing the same action over and over. I tried changing some hyper-parametrs, but no result. I also tried using target model and updating it every n episodes, which resulted in better convergence with gym CartPole environment, but still no effect on performance of my model in my custom environment. I have found a few discussions on reddit about the same problem, but none of them were answered.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a programming question. RL algorithms are notoriously unstable in their convergence, something you make a small change to a parameter and the whole thing breaks down.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Can you suggest please me where I can ask the question to get more detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too large changes to the current policy is the main cause of instability of A3C algorithm. There are methods to stabilize it, e.g. [TRPO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05477) or [PPO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347). I'd suggest you to look at PPO - it is very easy to implement, although less effective.

In PPO, you would simply change the loss function (based on the blog's notation) to:

[image: math formula]

Where it is recommended to use `e=0.2`. Good luck with your implementation!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my environment the agant always starts playing with a random place, so I decided to run it from the same place for a few episodes before changing its location to a random place. It sort of worked, but very unstable. It was sometimes properly converging and sometimes choosing the same action over and over again. I'll try implementing PRO, hopefully it helps